# Will there be a trace if I use a physical hard drive cloner to clone my hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I would like to know, I have seen an offline hard drive cloner on amazon, and I want to clone a hard drive, will it leave a trace of it being cloned.

thank you

Edit:

I've read the comments, and just to clarify further. This is the cloner I have seen http://tiny.cc/de65dz , I don't mind if its registered on the hard drive being powered on, but I do mind if there is some sort of history that files have been cloned or accessed which I am trying to avoid, if there is another way to clone a hard drive I would be open to suggestions.

thanks

Comment: Yes;  There will be traces.  How easily those traces can be found depends on the skill of the person looking for those traces.

Comment: what's the best way to clone a hard drive without leaving traces, I read something about writeblockers

Comment: If the cloning is done to a disk of exactly the same size, and is done bit-by-bit, I don't see how anyone can detect it. Except maybe by the sticker on the disk. Only disks with proprietary protection scheme (such as intentional bad sectors) may be impossible to copy.

Comment: Part of this depends on how much one scrutinizes there hdd.  SMART has certain power on statistics, like **power on hours**, that are either hard or impossible to change.  So if I have my PC on a power strip, make a note of the power on hours say 6000, shut PC down and turn off the power strip.  Then when I turn it back on again it should still be 6000.  So if its 6002, someone ran the drive for up to 1-2 hours while I was out.  However, that only proves the drive was on when it wasn't supposed to be.  While it does prove it was used none of them prove it was cloned.

Comment: Some drives have **242 Total_LBAs_Read**, and if I saw that jump up by say 60+gb worth I would suspect my drive had been cloned, but its not really proof.  Also you would have to really be monitoring this data more closely than any regular user ever would.  If I monitored every stat very closely I would definitely be suspicious if my drive was cloned.  However, that is probably not a provable level of proof.

Comment: @fawaddd Do you mean no trace on the source disk that someone took a copy? Or no trace on the target that it is a duplicate?

Comment: My eyebrow would raise, if I were to run data recovery on a disk, and it discovered files that I knew shouldn't exist.  Of course I use tamper tape (signed) on all my devices to detect this exact behavior.

Comment: @JRI No trace on the source Hard drive, that is being copied

Comment: @fawaddd - If you are doing something that isn’t allowed by policy you really should not proceed.  However, if we’re talking about trace evidence on the source HDD, there wouldn’t be any created with that particular cloning device. Seriously, if this is related to work, it’s not worth your job.  Administrators, have ways of knowing things, secrets we will take to our graves.

Answer (score 2):

Writeblockers shouldn't leave any traces unless someone finds evidence such as fingerprints or human hairs on the drive or other hardware. I would only go with a reputable company's write blocker if you want to be 100%

Comment: Having looked at write blockers, they are quite expensive, is there something you can suggest where I can copy a hard drive and the source hard drive doesn't leave a trail of it being copied or cloned

Comment: Write Blockers won't stop SMART statistics from being changed, right? (Also, [SSD garbage collection might occur whenever the device is simply powered on](https://www.klennet.com/notes/2018-04-16-write-blocking-ssd.aspx), but that might not be considered a trace in the context of the question.)

Comment: There is no way to guarantee without using a write blocker as most operating system immediately start writing to the drive as soon as it is plugged in. Most people would not notice however if you didn't use one.

Comment: @johndoe if the hard drive is plugged into an offline physical hard drive cloner, there shouldn't be a trace on the source HDD am I correct? As its not being plugged into an OS per say.

Answer (score 1):

If the cloning is done to a disk of exactly the same size, and is done
bit-by-bit, I don't see how anyone can detect it.

The only possibilities for detection that I see are:

- A missing required sticker on the new disk.
- Disk with proprietary protection scheme such as intentionally uncopiable bad sectors.

As regarding the source disk, no traces should be left on the disk for a
bit-by-bit copy. Such a copy does not modify any of the files on the disk
or their metadata (such as last-accessed).

If the disk supports SMART data, then its firmware will keep track of
the number of hours that the disk was running and the amount of data
that is read. Your risk is only if owner of the disk took note of
these values and has not allowed you to use it.
There is no way to falsify these values.

Comment: It's just the source hard disk I am more concerned about whether it leaves a trace or not

Comment: operating systems write to drives automatically

Comment: @johndoe: Not without a reason for doing so.